# Scrapy filter identical urls differ in "http" and "https"

Tags: scrapy

I notice that scrapy will crawl both pages that only differ in scheme, e.g. "http://www.google.com" and "https://www.google.com", which will actually double my request. Is there a way I can filter half of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic way. Depending on your specific circumstances different solutions may apply, or there may be no good solution.

If the issue is with a **specific domain**, you can just write your spider so that it will use the right protocol when yielding a new request.

If it is for a **broad crawl** targeting an arbitrary number of domains, it may be a bit tricky. Most domains will redirect HTTP to HTTPS, but some domains will redirect HTTPS traffic to HTTP.

In that latter case, if the problem is that while on an HTTPS page you get HTTP links that then redirect back to HTTPS, you could change your spider to read the protocol from `response.url` and using that when building a request instead of whatever the URL that you found uses. But it’s possible that some of the content is actually HTTP, and you will get bad responses due to the protocol change.